# Can I leave the UK for a few days without my wife (she has an EEA Family Visa)?

Tags: visas, uk, family, visa-sponsors

Me and my wife are currently in the UK. I'm a EU national and she is a non-eu national on a EEA family visa. Can I leave without her for a few days, leaving her alone in the UK? My job will require that.

Comment: Are you residing in the UK for a longer term or just visiting?

Comment: Possibly this question should be migrated in expatriate site.